# Can I get a working visa for Sweden if I am a Canadian Citizen? Can I get more than one?

Tags: visas, sweden, canadian-citizens

I am going to Sweden in June until october with my girlfriend. She is from Sweden and I have been told I can get a de-facto (partner) visa. Does anyone know what this means? Can I work on a visa like that? Is there a working visa for Sweden?

-Also, what are some main requirements for entering the country? (certain amount of money, health care, act)

---

I'm staying from the beginning of June until around September or October. I would like to be able to work, but it isn't necessary. I also plan on going back to sweden in about a year or so to stay for about a year or 2 and work, so I didn't want to use up a work visa for 4 - 5 months (if you can only get one).

Comment: How long do you want to stay for? A few weeks? A few months? Forever?

Comment: I'm staying from the beginning of June until around September. I would like to be able to work, but it isn't necessary. I also plan on going back to sweden in about a year or so to stay for about a year or 2 and work, so I didn't want to use up a work visa for 4 - 5 months this time. thats why i was wondering if and how the de-facto (relationship) visa works?

Comment: how do I make this unclosed? I edited it, and I see nothing wrong with the question??

Answer (score 5):

If you are a Canadian citizen with a Canadian passport and would like to travel to Sweden for a visit (tourism or business travel etc.) and your stay exceeds 90 days, you do require a visa.  You will need to follow the steps listed [here](http://canada.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/visas/general-information/) to formally apply.

Another note is that as a result of a Nordic representation agreement, Denmark has been handling visa applications for the Faroe Islands, Greenland, Iceland, Norway and Sweden since March 2008.

A great place to start with questions like this is a site called [VisaMapper](http://www.visamapper.com/). The map-based interface lets you check up on visa requirements of any country from the point of view of a traveler of any nationality. It’s always best to double check through official websites and organizations but it's a useful starting point.